# Load two return function with one click JSP and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

There is a jsp file calling 2 different js files. I had a button(assume ButtonA) in jsp which when clicked it load a function(Function1) which fill jsp form with values. There is another button in page (ButtonB) which when clicked it load another function where this function(Function2) calculate a figure based on result that Function1 populated in form. So the action was user click ButtonA first, field values loaded, then click ButtonB to get calculated figure. Now I dont want two button clicks here. I tried to put two functions in one button as example below

```
<td colspan=3><center><INPUT TYPE="Button"  VALUE="Query Package Info" TARGET="bottom" onClick="generateReport('MK07FormPackageInfo'); computeMarkFormat(document.MK07Form.markSurf.value);"></td>
```

but it only correctly run first one but the second one with gives empty values.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have the Javascript Function1 just call Function2.

If Function 1 and 2 are used by other JSP's:
Function 1 could be overloaded or modified to take in a parameter that says call function2 or not. Other JSP's can still keep calling Function1 as is. This particular button can call Function1 with parameter to trigger 
Function 2 call.

```
 function1 (callFunction2) {
   function1();
   function2();
 }
 function1 (){
 }

 function2 () {
 }
```

Is there another reason you need this to be two seperate calls?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: because both are global javascript functions which are being shared by other jsp too.

Comment: Both function are different .js files and have their own different specific role. I would not like to mix up their functionality in this way actually.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute your scenario, it is working actually.

Here is my code

```
<script language="javascript">
function loadValues(){
document.getElementById('a').value = '2';
document.getElementById('b').value = '2';
}

function calc(){
document.getElementById('c').value = document.getElementById('a').value + document.getElementById('b').value;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="a"/>
<input type="text" id="b"/>
<input type="text" id="c"/>
<input type="button" onClick="loadValues(); calc();" />
```

Only place where it fails is, if your first method executed successfully then only the second function will be executed. If you have any exception or problem in first function, the second one will not work, you may try to give 'b1' instead of 'b' After then nothing will be executed. Correct me if something wrong. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a close tag for <center> ?

You may need to debug or add console.log to debug your second function if the result is not what you expected(Since you said it returned empty val, which means it actually got called, right?). Also, try to open console on browser's developer tool and see if any Exception/Error.

Btw, just like other guys says:
onClick="generateReport('MK07FormPackageInfo'); computeMarkFormat(document.MK07Form.markSurf.value);"

Isn't really pretty and is not a recommend way to do this...
You may want to add multiple event Listener to your  using jQuery:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" />
<!-- watever here -->

<INPUT id="queryPackageInfoBtn" TYPE="Button"  VALUE="Query Package Info" TARGET="bottom" />

<!-- watever here -->


<!--
   Binding the even
-->
<script>
  jQuery('#queryPackageInfoBtn').click(function(){generateReport('MK07FormPackageInfo'); });
  jQuery('#queryPackageInfoBtn').click(function(){computeMarkFormat(document.MK07Form.markSurf.value);});  
</script>  
 

<!--
actually you can just do:
jQuery('#queryPackageInfoBtn').click(function(){
  generateReport('MK07FormPackageInfo');
  computeMarkFormat(document.MK07Form.markSurf.value); 
});

but I want to make it obvious how you can add multiple event handler to the buttons without using inline onClick which will be messy.
-->
```